# How to remove 404 error in admin panel after uploading module in running website in magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, third-party-module, 404-page

Hello everyone i uploaded live chat module in my running website.But after uploading i get 404 error in live chat module.i tried many ways to remove it like **flush cache,logout and login again**.but still it appear. what should i do for this??
plz help me

Comment: check error in var/log folder

Comment: check the compiler it enabled ?

Comment: can you share extension code otherwise its impossible to know what is the error over there

Comment: Please check magento logs and server logs also check magento compilation is enable or not. That extension compilable to Magento 1.9.

Comment: yes i checked compilation is not enabled.but how to check server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting 404 error in your module section in admin? Or its giving error on admin itself? Please try renaming the cache and session folder and also double check if all the files are uploaded correctly.